# error: The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong such that widget.event on line 15 is showing the mentioned error. I believe initState can fix it but I can't for the life of me work out how I implement it.

```
class _EventDetailsScreenState extends State<EventDetailsScreen> {
  final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final _eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('events/' + widget.event['eventId']);
```

The full code is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class EventDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final event;

  EventDetailsScreen({Key? key, this.event}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventDetailsScreenState createState() => _EventDetailsScreenState();
}

class _EventDetailsScreenState extends State<EventDetailsScreen> {
  final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final _eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('events/' + widget.event['eventId']);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.event['eventName']),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _eventRef.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final event = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Event Name: ' + event['eventName']),
                  Text('Event Date: ' + event['eventDate']),
                  Text('Event Time: ' + event['eventTime']),
                  Text('Event Location: ' + event['eventLocation']),
                  Text('Invited Users: ' + event['invitedUsers'].toString()),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text('Loading'));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to implement initState but I can't seem to get it right, and nay adjustments I make seem to lead to more errors. It is my last error and it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line of code

```
final _eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('events/' + widget.event['eventId']);
```

You can't use "widget" like that, but you can simply fix this by adding the "late" keyword

```
late final _eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('events/' + widget.event['eventId']);
```

Comment: +1 thank you, this solved it. I couldn't find the answer anywhere. I knew I had it wrong but couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 2):

As an explanation: you can't access the `widget` property inside of the constructor, or for initializing the members of the state object, because the state object is only mounted (connected to the widget) right before the `initState` method is called.

```dart
  late final DatabaseReference _eventRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('events/' + widget.event['eventId']);
  }
```

The other answer from @jabguru is also an option with the inline `late final` initilizer, because the right side (the initialization) will only be called when the member variable is accessed the first time.